# Django settings LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL doesn't work

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django 1.8.7 with the following apps installed:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'bootstrap3',
'myapp',
'storages',
'rest_framework',
'django_tables2',]
```

I use the built-in django.contrib.auth.urls to create my pages for login, password change, etc. 
I set my LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL in the settings.py to '/home', exactly like I did with LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL. Logging out a user via the page works fine, but I stil remain at the logout page afterwards. This is not a problem when logging in, the login redirect works like it should.

a part of my urls.py:

```
url(r'^accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'), {'template_name': 'registration/login.html'}),
```

my settings.py:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/home'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/home'
```

Thanks in advance for any help or ideas!

Comment: It doesn't make sense to have `{'template_name': 'registration/login.html'}` when you include `django.contrib.auth.urls` - that will override the template name for *all* the auth views, not just the login view. Note that the default is `registration/login.html` already.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL` setting was [added in Django 1.10](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/releases/1.10/#django-contrib-auth).

On earlier versions of Django, you can set `next_page` in your URL pattern for the `logout` view.

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.auth import views

url_patterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^logout/$', views.logout, {'next_page': settings.LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL}, name='logout'),
    ...
]
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I will switch to a new version then.

Answer (score 9):

As per Django 2.1 (2019), you can do something like this

1). In settings.py
    set 
    LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'name of url you would like to redirect to'

2). In urls.py

```
import settings
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
    ...,
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(next_page=settings.LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL), name='logout'),
    ...,
]
```

Comment: I tried this but nothing changed for me. Is there anything else I can do to make my LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL work? If this information helps, I am also using keycloak.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are redirecting to the same home page in both cases.By both cases i mean login and logout.You should redirect the LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/login-page'(u should redirect it to the login page).